Confusion in saving a C# Datetime? to a PostgreSQL date column (via dapper and npgsql)
Can someone please explain why converting a C# datetime to string before passing it into PostgreSQL via dapper and npgsql results in correctly saving the date; whereas passing the C# datetime object directly to PostgreSQL (via dapper and npgsql) results in losing a day???
Here are the details:
In PostgreSQL (version 14), I have a column defined as:
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS phoenix.returntooffice
    ADD COLUMN rtoon date;

In the C# script using dapper:
 var q = connection.QuerySingle<ReturnToOfficeOrder>(sql, new
            {
                Rtoon = r.rtoon?.ToString()    //This works correctly with   @Rtoon::date                                
            });

where sql is:

with _in ( rtoon) as (
        values ( @Rtoon::date)
),.......

The above code works correctly to save the correct datetime to postgre; however, if I use:
Rtoon = r.rtoon

where r.rtoon is the C# Datetime? ojbect, postgresql sees @Rtoon::date as one day before that of rtoon.
I have studied through all the documentation regarding UTC, postgre, and npgsql -- but in the end am more confused than ever.
Any help is most appreciated.

This issue is usually related to time zone conversions. If your local time zone is behind UTC, this could shift the date back one day.
Recommendations:

Explicitly handle time zone by converting 'DateTime' objects to UTC before sending them to the database.

Use DateTimeOffset type so the time zone is clearer in context of date and time.

Adjust how npgsql treats 'DateTimeKind.Unspecified' by using 'NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder' to ensure a consistent behaviour.



I tried converting to UTC before sending them to the database -- it failed. I'm not familiar with DateTimeOffset,. I do not see any direct management of Npgsql when using Dapper. :(
